# ndis.sys BSOD after installing VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bsod

I have just installed VirtualBox and it installed perfectly and ran fine until I went to restart my computer. After a restart I blue screened, with `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` caused by driver `ndis.sys`.

I have attempted to start the computer in safe mode which works fine but safe mode with networking causes it to blue screen. I would like to uninstall VirtualBox but this is not possible in safe mode so I need to fix enough of the problem to be able to boot without a blue screen to uninstall.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/117840-uninstall-remove-software-safe-mode.html

Comment: I have uninstalled virtualbox but the problem still persists, any ideas what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ndis.sys is your network controller. When you installed VirtualBox it most likely added a few network controller which somehow conflicted with your current one - your network controlled being messed up explains why you can't boot into safe mode without working, so it's a good indicator that this is your actual problem.

To get rid of the BSOD, however, try going to your Device Manager in Safe Mode, find your network adapter, and Uninstall it. Then you should hopefully be able to boot back into normal Windows, download a networking driver on another computer, and install a new one.

Comment: I have uninstalled my network adapters (I had 3 of them) and now it is working perfectly (without network of course)

Comment: Good! What network adapters are they, specifically?

Comment: The wireless one is a D-Link DWA-556 Xtreme N and I have two intel ones built into the motherboard that windows has automatically downloaded drivers for, in short everything seems to be working fine and I have even used it as an excuse to make some backups. Will restart now to see if there is any problems with the drivers.

Comment: @user2248702 There's a known clash between the VBox networking drivers and some programs - and it's usually enough to just disable the VBox ones (which of course also prevents host-only networks, though internal, NAT and bridged should still work). I can't remember which specific programs, but something along the lines of NetLimiter or NetMonitor might be one of them.